# Enclose layout as an inner content of a bigger layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, code-reuse

I have a basic container layout in which inside it I have a `FrameLayout` with an id `@android:id/content`. This `FrameLayout` meant for other layouts to fill it.

Now my question is this:

Lets say I have a layout file `content.xml` which I want it's content to fill the said `FrameLayout`.Is there a way to do all this in XML?

I want something like the `<include>` tag, but the exact opposite. Call it `<included-in>`.

Is there such a thing or way to achieve it, or do I have to inflate them both, and insert the content in code?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to do it in Java code. It is disappointing that Android doesn't have a feature like template engine like Jade or the one in Django. Which makes it hard to write "DRY" layout files especially when you want to reuse the enclosing part.